# SCIM filter parsing

Tags: rest, scim

I want to use the SCIM filtering format for my REST service.

**Question 1:** 
Can I use this for my internal REST service? 
Means my query parameter q will contain string like this **&q=(productName co 4) and (productName co JAM)**. Can I use it?

**Question 2:**
Are there any available API's which will parse this kind of string?

**Question 3:**
What is the best and ideal way to construct the where clause from this string?

Thanks, Vijay